# How can I make sure my app doesn't get stolen by a developer

Tags: ios

I made an app and I don't have the knowledge to add a few things that I want. I found a developer online. How can I protect my app to make sure it doesn't get stolen?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about legal and business issues,  not programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give him your source code, no technical measures can stop him from stealing the source code. If he were local to you, you could require him to use a locked-down computer in your own office, but I don't think that is an option for you.

If your app has substantial non-code assets (graphics, sound, databases, etc.) you could give him only the minimal subset of assets necessary for testing.

If the app talks to a server you control, and you don't also give him the code/data to set up his own server, then him stealing your code may be less harmful.

Other than that, you need to consider legal enforcement, not technical enforcement.

Comment: Rob, If I were to upload my current version to the app store and then I hire a developer to update it, does that secure my app so they won't steal it?

Comment: That doesn't provide any technical enforcement. You'd have to complain to Apple to have his version taken down.